# Babel loader for vue chart js

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

i'm trying to use vue chart js in my project, my webpack version is 4.46 and according to this [github issue](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/1002) it's causing a loader error for vue chart js

```
Loading...
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js 198:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (198:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|             const ref = shallowRef(null);
|             const reforwardRef = (chartRef)=>{
>                 ref.value = chartRef?.chart;
|             };
|             expose({
```

the guy in the issue says

```
Looks like you are using Webpack 4. It doesn't support some modern syntax, so you should use babel-loader to transpile vue-chartjs and chart.js
```

and i need to create a babel loader for that. i'm totally clueless when it comes to creating a babel loader and don't know what to do and where to begin.. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue this morning, you can just use older version of chart.js:

```
npm install vue-chartjs@^3.0.0 chart.js@^2.0.0
```